# Search for continuation line

Tags: search, indentation

How to search for continuation line, as detected by c-indent in vim ?
[ie. the +N cinoption](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim's source code has a section dedicated to do this, and it's a lot more complicated than a simple regex. Here's a link to the [neovim file](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/0bce4dc54427d05ab320a88f6269a9c1b05ea899/src/nvim/indent_c.c) that does this.

This leaves you with 2 options:

1. Write your own regex to do a "close enough" guess job
2. If you're using the +N option and can define continuation lines as lines that are indented N spaces more than the line before. You can use a regex to find these lines:

   ```
   \v^( +)\S.*\n\1    \zs\S
   \v                       "very magic mode" so we don't have to escape too many things
     ^                      start of a line
      ( +)                  all the spaces, captured in group 1
          \S                a non-space character
            .*              the rest of this line
              \n            newline
                \1          the same number of spaces again
                      \zs   N extra spaces, then start the match
                         \S a non-space
   ```

Comment: indeed, not an easy job.